# Sometime it creates an error because there is no constructor and sometimes it's OK

Tags: java, constructor

Why does this code fail to compile with "Apple needs a constructor"?

```
class Fruit {
  public Fruit(String name) {
    System.out.println("Fruit's constructor is invoked");
  }
}

public class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

This code has a class without constructor (GraduateStudent) and it's OK?

```
public class Demo{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    m(new GraduateStudent());
    m(new Student());
    m(new Person());
    m(new Object());
  }

  public static void m(Object x) {
    System.out.println(x.toString());
  }
}

class GraduateStudent extends Student {
}

class Student extends Person {
  public String toString() {
    return "Student";
  }
}

class Person extends Object {
  public String toString() {
    return "Person";
  }
}
```